# дерево каталогов, и список файлов в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtreeview

Нужно ***вставить дерево каталогов, и список файлов***, в приложение на **PyQt5**, в документации не нашел.

Может кто-то знает как релизовать(скриншоты ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

````
import sys
import ftplib
import easygui

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

# msg = "Введите информацию о сервере"
# fieldNames = ["IP Сервера", "Логин", "Пароль"]
# title = 'FTP' 
# ftp_log = easygui.multpasswordbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.1', 'Artem', '1204')
# ftp.cwd('/disk1_1')


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = QGridLayout()

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.file = self.menubar.addMenu('&Опции')
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)    
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        self.ftp_lst()
        self.a = None                                                  

    def ftp_lst(self):
        self.file_lst = ftp.nlst()
        self.len_file_lst = len(ftp.nlst())
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(self.len_file_lst) for j in range(1)]
        for position, name in zip(positions, self.file_lst):
            if name == '':
                continue
            self.button = QPushButton(name)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.button, *position)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.show()

    def update(self):
        self.ftp_lst()

    def on_click(self):
        a = self.sender()      
        ftp.cwd(f'{ftp.pwd()}/{a.text()}')
        self.update()
        print(ftp.pwd())
        print(a.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня нет некоторых модулей, с которыми вы работаете, 
поэтому я кое что закомментировал. 
Раскомментируйте строки помеченные `# #@`

Я не вижу общего дизайна вашего приложения,
поэтому вставьте

```
self.grid.addWidget(self.tree, ...)
```

где вам надо.

```
import sys
import ftplib
#@ import easygui                                                         # #@

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                                # +++
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

# msg = "Введите информацию о сервере"
# fieldNames = ["IP Сервера", "Логин", "Пароль"]
# title = 'FTP' 
# ftp_log = easygui.multpasswordbox(msg, title, fieldNames)

#@ ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.1', 'Artem', '1204')                        # #@

# ftp.cwd('/disk1_1')


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)                                      # +++ self

        self.menubar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.file = self.menubar.addMenu('&Опции')
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)    

#@        self.ftp_lst()                                                    # #@
        self.a = None   

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.tree, 111, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         

    def ftp_lst(self):
        self.file_lst = ftp.nlst()
        self.len_file_lst = len(ftp.nlst())
#        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(self.len_file_lst) for j in range(1)]
        for position, name in zip(positions, self.file_lst):
            if name == '':
                continue
            self.button = QPushButton(name)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.button, *position)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
# ?       self.show()

    def update(self):
        self.ftp_lst()

    def on_click(self):
        a = self.sender()      
        ftp.cwd(f'{ftp.pwd()}/{a.text()}')
        self.update()
        print(ftp.pwd())
        print(a.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(640, 480)                    # +
    ex.show()                              # +++ !!!
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]